# How to fix Jupiter autostart?

Tags: 11.10, jupiter

I accidentally delete the option for jupiter applet from Startup Applications. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You'll need two startup commands:

- Jupiter

  `/usr/bin/jupiter`

and

- Jupiter Restore

  `/usr/lib/jupiter/scripts/jupiter`

Alternatively - just purge `jupiter` and reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get purge jupiter
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```